# IOS UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification not firing in background mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I'm writing an IOS application which will record ( over time ) the current battery level of the iPhone device.

I have working code executing within the foreground using UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification, this fires a notification ( which is handled successfully ) when the app in in foreground mode.

Code is as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] setBatteryMonitoringEnabled:YES];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(batteryChanged:) name:UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification object:nil];
    return YES;
}

- (void)batteryChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"Battery Changed From Observer");
    [self UpdateBatteryStatus];
}

-(void)UpdateBatteryStatus
{
    UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    double batLeft = (float)[myDevice batteryLevel] * 100;
    NSLog(@"Battery level: %f", batLeft);
    // Do some stuff related to battery status
}
```

This executes ( output via log proves it ) every 1% increment ( or decrement ) on the battery status on the phone, which works exactly as expected.

When the app is moved to the background however, the events stop firing. Upon moving the app back to the foreground, the events fire ( it's almost like they are queued up until it reaches the foreground ).

I have searched stack overflow, and most answers are all the same, basically this is a background-mode permissions problem. So I ticked all the boxes:
[image]

I added everything just to make sure it wasn't a background persmission problem. Unfortunately, even after a clean, and rebuild ( also a shutdown of Xcode, and re-plugin of iPhone ) the events still do not fire.

Please bear in mind, I have no intention of releasing this to the app store, I'm aware that faking background-mode use cases is a quick and easy rejection. But I would like to get it working for personal usage.

Edit: ios target 11.3

Comment: Battery monitoring is not a supported background mode

Comment: @Paulw11 does that mean that it is not that anything is setup incorrectly, it's just not firing the UIDeviceBatteryLevelDidChangeNotification event because that event is never fired in background mode?

Comment: That is correct; your app only executes in the background in response to events for the specific background modes you have configured and enabled in your app; e.g. Location services where you have enabled the capability and configured a `CLLocationManager` instance for background updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your app won't get `NSNotificationCenter` notifications while being in background/suspended. What you could try is to use fetch background mode to mimic remote downloads. Note however downsides of this approach - system itself will decide when to call the callback.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [application setMinimumBackgroundFetchInterval:UIApplicationBackgroundFetchIntervalMinimum]; 

    return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application performFetchWithCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler
{
    UIDevice *myDevice = [UIDevice currentDevice];
    double batLeft = (float)[myDevice batteryLevel] * 100;
    NSLog(@"Battery level: %f", batLeft);

    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
}
```

If you as stated do not plan to release your app in AppStore you can try another hacks with background modes like infinite playing a muted sound in background.

Comment: Marking as answer, basically, had to go the route of the muted sound in the background.